# How to unzip a file in azure logic apps without using azure functions

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps, zip

I have .dat.zip files in sharepoint, am extracting them into adls using azure logic apps, is there any way to unzip the files in logic apps and write the file into adls?

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is no direct action to extract an archive file to other services, you have to extract an archive file to a SharePoint folder then upload these files to other services path. If you could accept this, you could refer to my below flow.

I create a dynamic folder with the value from the request to store the files, then extract files to this folder and list all files in this folder.

**Note**: the destination folder path in the `Extract folder` is different from the List folder `File Identifier`.

[image]

After listing the files, use this list to get all files content and upload them to data lake.

[image]